# How to select multiple items in pyqt5 QlistWidget and print them

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Im using qt designer and trying to print out all the items I select in a QlistWidget it only prints out one item. I have selectionMode set to MulitSelection

selected listed from the list:

- Commvault Install
- Veeam Install

code

```
session_name_=self.listWidget.currentItem().text()

addendant_=self.listWidget_2.currentRow()
scheduled_=self.dateTimeEdit.dateTime()
sched=scheduled_.toString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm ap")
    
print(session_name_)
```

It will only return one item

```
python3 template.py 
('Veeam Install',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You request the [`currentItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentItem), instead of the [`selectedItems`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems). The current item is a single element (typically the last selected item), whereas the selected items is a list of all the selected items.